# Limiting background-color to width of heading

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a background color to stick strictly to the text of the heading and not span the entire width of the page. I understand that block level elements take up the entire width of the page, so I was wondering if there was a way around this besides forcing inline styles.

**EDIT:** If I were to use display: inline-block; why is it that even though I specify `text-align: center;` my headers are still left aligned? Should I use a float instead?

Comment: Why not apply the background color to the text element?

Comment: you should text-align the parent of the heading, and also set auto margins for the width.

Answer (score 5):

Or displaying as an inline-block could meet most use cases:

`h1 {
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
}`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

In HTML:

```
<div id="Heading">
   <span id="HeadingText">HEADING TEXT</span>
</div>
```

In CSS:

```
#Heading
{
   /* Formatting of full heading */
}

#HeadingText
{
   /* Formatting for just heading text */
   background-color: #00ff00;
}
```

Guessing from your question, this isn't the answer you are looking for, but it may be useful.

EDIT:

Alternatively, this should work as well.  But I'm pretty sure this is what you want to avoid (inline, right?)...

```
<h1 style="background-color:#660000; display:inline;">Heading<h1>
```

Comment: Thank you! For future reference, is it better style to force inline-block or to wrap block tags in divs?

Comment: To be honest, that's not a question I am capable of answering.  I don't rightly know what the best practices are.  Sorry. However, I would guess it would probably be best to use inline or inline-block instead of DIVs.

Comment: inline-block seems to actually be what I was after, however that screws up my ability to center align the elements.

Comment: If you use inline-block and want to center the text, I think you need to use text-align: center of the parent element of your inline element.

Answer (score 0):

This would solve this problem I think:

```
<div id="Heading">
   <div id="HeadingText">HEADING TEXT</div>
</div>
```

And your css would be:

```
#Heading{
    background-color:#CCC;
}
#HeadingText{
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#FF0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the text-align:center; attribute to the parent element containing your div block to center your header and its background with display:inline-block;

Comment: Thank you! Do you know the reason for that by the way?